# Enabling Kubuntu-Desktop in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, kubuntu, kde

I installed kubuntu-desktop and I still get the Unity desktop. How do I enable the KDE desktop?

Answer (score 3):

You need to log out first, click the circular Ubuntu icon near the password prompt and choose "KDE". Now, you can log in and use KDE. Reopen this menu and select "Ubuntu" if you like to use Unity again.

Comment: Is there a reason you recommend selecting "KDE" rather than "Kubuntu" as the session type? (If I recall correctly, that's the default session type in a system installed as Kubuntu, and it's available if `kubuntu-desktop` is installed.)

Comment: As far as I know, it's something in the line of "KDE Plasma Active Desktop".

Comment: Thank you. I tried it and then I ended up uninstalling it seeing it sucks

Comment: You're entitled to your own opinion :)